# React router navigate to specific route without pushing it again

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a web app that has 6-7 routes. User sees screens in this order:

1. Home
2. Players List
3. Enter A number
4. Game screen
5. Game end screen for winner-loser

After **Screen 5**, I want to display **Screen 3** for the play again. So I don't need "**Game Screen**" and "**Game End Screen**" any more and **clean** them from history and return to screen 3.

I'm using `<MemoryRouter>` component to prevent url changes and using a custom "Back" button for going back. I actually wonder is it possible to alter route stack manually (removing some of them etc). Or Which method should I use? I tried all of them btw.

I'm sharing a `console.log(history)` here

```
{length: 6, action: "PUSH", location: {…}, index: 5, entries: Array(6), …}
length: 7
action: "PUSH"
location: {pathname: "/gamescreen", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "pwi569"}
index: 6
entries: Array(7)
0: {pathname: "/", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "8zl7xq"}
1: {pathname: "/playerlist", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "ximj74"}
2: {pathname: "/enteryournumber", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "hxx63i"}
3: {pathname: "/gamescreen", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "s601nx"}
4: {pathname: "/modalgameend", state: {…}, search: "", hash: "", key: "i8chfy"}
5: {pathname: "/enteryournumber", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "ozqjyr"}
6: {pathname: "/gamescreen", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "pwi569"}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
createHref: ƒ createPath(location)
push: ƒ push(path, state)
replace: ƒ replace(path, state)
go: ƒ go(n)
goBack: ƒ goBack()
goForward: ƒ goForward()
canGo: ƒ canGo(n)
block: ƒ block(prompt)
listen: ƒ listen(listener)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following for removing the previous entries from the history stack.

```
this.props.history.replace("/enteryournumber");
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a Play Again button will be there in 'Game end screen for winner-loser' screen.

Write a onClick event on that button to redirect programmatically.

```
playAgain() {
   return <Redirect to='/enteryournumber' />
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it does the same thing with the `this.props.history.replace("route")`. If I use replace-redirect repeatedly, I corrupt "go back" system. Thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it. On "Game End Screen" I added a line like this:

`this.props.history.entries.length=2;`

So I have only first two screens in stack, "Home" And "PlayerList". After that I can push any screen what I want;

`this.props.history.push("/enteryournumber");`